# Wix installer: How to ask user to provide a file path needed by application configuration

Tags: installation, wix

I am developing a Chrome extension for my company. The extension uses Chrome native messaging, so I am using Wix to create an installer for the host application (Just copy the binary and write a specific registry).

The native host application needs a configuration file, because the host application is performing crypto operations and in order to do that, the user needs to provide his pkcs12 keystore with signing certificates.

My first thought was to create the configuration file during installation. User would provide a path to his keystore file, the installer would write that path into the config file and copy it into the installation directory next to the host binary. I was searching the internet for hours just to find out it is not possible to select a file using Wix, only a directory.

My question is, is this actually true and there is really no way of doing this, and if so, what would you suggest? It's not very user-friendly to ask users to copy their keystore into a particular location. My second idea was to just put a text field and tell the user to fill in the path to their keystore file, but that isn't user-friendly either.

Thank you for all your suggestions

Comment: There are several issues that have to be resolved, which turn any proper answer into a complex one. What should happen on installation rollback? What should happen on successful uninstallation? What should happen on uninstallation rollback? What should happen on installation of new version (you probably want to reuse the setting)? What should happen when another user wants to use the extension? Is installation actually per machine or per user? These are all general questions, not specific to your problem. I am no expert, but because of these unanswered questions experts avoid giving answers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't think any of those things is actually relevant for my issue, I can solve those myself. I just want to know whether there is a user-friendly way to ask a file path from user.

Currently I just decided to use nsis, because nsis has a feature which allows me to prompt use for a file path, but I like Wix more so I am kinda sad I can't use it right now